# How to validate the attributes before calling the method save in CActiveRecord?

Tags: php, yii

Say I have a model project, the owner_id stands for the owner of the project. When creating a new project, user need to type the name of the owner instead of id. I  write a method to validate to make sure that the user do exist in the system and then I can get the id of the user. The rule is:

```
 array('owner_name', 'userValidation')
```

But I find that the validation is called only when the statement below is executing

```
 $model->save()
```

which means that if I try to get the id of an user not in the system before the saving with the statements

```
 $model->validate();
 $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$model->owner_name));
 $model->owner_id=$user->id;
```

there will be an exception. So my question is why the validation doesn't work as expected when I call the validate() method? I have checked the source code of method save in Yii

```
 public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
    {
            if(!$runValidation || $this->validate($attributes))
                    return $this->getIsNewRecord() ? $this->insert($attributes) : $this->update($attributes);
            else
                    return false;
    }
```

I think it also try to validate by call the validate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not check the return value from validate(). Try something like this:

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$model->owner_name));
    $model->owner_id=$user->id;
    /// ...
} else {
    // handle the case that userValidation failed
}
```